# Problem of late insertion in mysql database

Tags: mysql

While I am inserting approx 50000 or more rows in a database, It seems insertion still running in backend even though database pointer is seems free in process.

every time I refresh the database, total rows shows increasing every time.

So should I use transaction to insert them in a single stroke?

Comment: What does "refresh the database" mean? In InnoDB, the only way to find out the exact row count is to run a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` query.

Comment: What is "*database pointer*"?

Comment: @Alvaro refreshing means every time I execute this statement"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of transactions is to be able to rollback the complete process if one of the insertions fail. It makes no sense to use transactions as a way to speed up things since it obviously adds additional overhead, thus making it all slower.

Comment: In future I will not even think to use transaction for speeding up insertion or updation. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

No, don't insert so many rows in a single transaction. You would end up running out of log space.